Details of an ALF episode with Ann Meara: Did she threaten ALF?
I have a fairly clear recollection of an episode in which a conversation between her and the father of the family goes something like this:
Father: It's amazing how rapidly the sense of wonder [at meeting an ETI] fades
Anne Meara's Character: Yeah and is replaced by a desire for a small-sized body bag and a baseball bat...
I'd be amazed if I made this exchange up, it is pretty funny. Can anyone ideally find the clip? If I saw it, I think it was on TV and I have found I believe an episode of ALF with her, but not this specific dialog. My guess is that Jerry Stahl wrote it. (Complete guess, but it makes some sense, I think.) Note: I see in Wikipedia that it was actually Anne Meara herself who wrote the episode although as I understand, one writer is credited while many writers often (always?) contribute to a tv script and perhaps Stahl was one such writer.

From "Breakup to Makeup" (Season 4, Episode 10)

It's a quick drop from wonderment to aggravation, isn't it, Whizzer?



So, Dorothy, can I get you something?
A cab? A rickshaw? A broom?



No, maybe just a baseball bat and a small body bag.

